# Table Output format in Neo4j

Tags: user-interface, neo4j, graph-databases, dashboard

I am exploring on Neo4j capabilities to create dashboards and looking for 2 specific functionalities.

1) Is it possible to have a dashboard in which upper half consists of graph chart and lower half shows data of a node in tabular format when someone clicks on any node.

2) Can we provide customize size for each node. I read that we can provide the same size of nodes of each label but I want if we are showing sales by each node then node with higher sales should be bigger in size and vice versa.

Comment: Neo4j is a database, not a UI tool, even if it display some graph viz in its browser. For my POV, you need to create a web application with a javascript Graph library (like sigmajs, viz.js, ...)

Comment: @logisima hey, thanks for your response. Also for the purpose of sharing our charts with user I saw that another person can download neo4j and use our code. but they don't have any UI for user only where only graphs are shown. For that also we need to create web applications?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand ... What do you mean by `I saw that another person can download neo4j and use our code` ?

Comment: @logisima I mean I want to share my report. If I share my cypher queries someone can use them and view the graphs I have created. But that would in a developer version. Does Neo4j has any offering where in I can just show the graphs and share them with user

Comment: Like I said, Neo4j is a database, not a dashboard tool. You can download the PNG or SVG of your graph from the browser, but that's all. For other needs, you need an  extra tool, or to build it.

Comment: @logisima got that, thank you so much :)